# Hide Navigation Bar in Specific View - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xcode8.2

I have NavigationController that handles navigation through my app.
According to my design, the very first view should have no visible NavigationBar. All the others after, will.

In this FirstView, I'm using this so far to hide the NavBar, inside the ViewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

From this FirstView I can access other Views. In these other views I show the NavBar using:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

My problem is that:

- When I navigate from a View with Visible NavBar, back to the FirstView with the Hidden NavBar, the NavBar is now visible.
  Basically the NavBar only hides the very first time then shows if I use the back button.

How Can I Prevent this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move that code to `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`.

`viewDidLoad()` is only called once per instantiated view controller, whereas `viewWillAppear()` is called whenever the view controller is about to be presented on screen.

You can read more about the view controller lifecycle [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3).

Comment: I understand my mistake now.
I was putting the viewWillAppear within the viewDidLoad...
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Write below code in your **FirstViewController**'s **viewWillAppear** method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated);
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

And in your **SecondViewController**'s **viewWillAppear** method write below code

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated);
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Do not try to hide and show nav bar in **viewWillAppear** and **viewWillDisappear** subsequetly in **FirstViewController**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to hide NavigationBar with cool animation:

```
 func setupAnimationForNavigationBar(caseOfFunction: Bool) {
    if caseOfFunction == true {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -200)
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }

}
```

If you want to hide NavigationBar, so set it "True" and if you want to call NavigationBar again, set it "False"